# How to connect HSQL (file based) with my android app?

Tags: android, database, hsqldb

Hello I have a problem connecting my android app to HSQLDB.

First question:

Is there a specific android jar for HSQLDB that i should use or could I use any HSQL jar?

Second question:

If I can use the provided jar. How can I get the connection to work and what should I place in the Class.forName("") as I was getting a ClassNotFoundException error when using:
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver") or Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver").newInstance() ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you include the jar in your Android project? If HSQLDB doesn't use any APIs not available on Android, it should work as is. BTW, why not just use SQLite which is built in Android?

Comment: I did include hsqldb.jar I tried to import it to make sure it is there, and it worked. As for why using HSQLDB: I am using an hsqldb  .script file from my desktop application and trying to reconstruct the database on the android app.

Comment: There are two possibilities -- either the jar was included in your project, but not in the final Android APK, or it uses some class not found on Android. In any case, port your scripts to SQLite shouldn't be too difficult. That would save you a lot trouble later on.

Comment: But the HSQL scripts wont be fully compatible with sqlite and I dont want to use adapters. Not even Sqlite is compatible with android's Sqlite

Comment: There a different versions with some differences, but SQLite is SQLite. It's platform independent. Don't use adapters, just re-write your scripts in SQLite syntax (should be mostly the same unless you are using arcane features).

Comment: Everything will be dynamic. I need to export a package in which my .script file is and I want to open it with my android app, so I wont have the chance to modify my script. I will look into the inclusion of the jar in the apk.

Comment: This is hardly a portable and reliable way to share data. Export your data in some sort of standard format (CSV, XML, JSON) and import it in your Android app.

Comment: What i meant in "my package" is that my application exports 3D data and its properties. The properties are in an HSQLDB .script file. All I want to do is read that script in android app and store them in a file based database. Since I'm using hsql in my desktop app I thought of hsql in android.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to establish a connection to an HSqlDB in Android 4.1.

Anyone who's looking to do this in Eclipse, make sure you have the hsqldb.jar in your libraries and make sure it's exported.  All of this is in the Project > Java Build Path in Eclipse.

I'm able to make a connection and it has created a new set of database files.  I'm using a file based db.  Specifically I'm building a LibGDX game for Ouya, but it should work for any android project.  The code that runs Hsql is in a completely different project from the Android project, so I needed to have it as a library for both, and to have it exported from the Android project.

Answer (score 0):

This is many years old but I think I found the problem. You need to make sure you have the hsqldb.jar that is compiled for the jdk appropriate for your target version of Android. In my case, I needed to download hsqldb-2.6.0-jdk6.jar. At the time I'm posting this, Android 11 (30) only supports up to jdk 8. The current "latest" release version (2.6) of hsqldb.jar is 11.