# HSQLDB cant connect to db script with android?

Tags: android, hsqldb

I want to access a hsqldb database using android, but i get this error everytime `java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@dc61f9b4[file =/home/user/db/jade.lck,`

this is my connexion class:

```
 private static final String BDD_DRIVER = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
private static final String BDD_URI = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:home/user/db/jade;shutdown=true";
private static final String BDD_LOGIN = "sa";
private static final String BDD_PASS = "";
```

and this is how i get the connection:

```
 Class.forName(BDD_DRIVER).newInstance();
        connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(BDD_URI, BDD_LOGIN, BDD_PASS);
```

thank you for helping me.

Comment: There is no separate release of the hsqldb for Android.

Comment: i found this link, he did it with android?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576512/4368432    so what can i do? i need to get data stored in hsqldb database.

Comment: I think that is not possible, for there is no doc related to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the error that you reported, it means the hsqldb.jar is present and an attempt was made to connect to the database. You must report the full error because after the file name, it includes the reason why there was a failure.

The full error means the directory indicated by `jdbc:hsqldb:file:home/user/db/` does not exist, or it is a read-only directory where the `.lck` file cannot be created.

In order to narrow down the cause, you should find the correct absolute path by trying to list the existing .script file using a Java file method. An absolute path starts with the `/` character. You can then try to open the database as `readonly`, which does not create a `.lck` file. If this is successful, you can try to open the database normally.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@e768051[file =/db/jade.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /db/jade.lck: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)